# Opencart Products API

Tags: php, api, opencart

I installed opencart tool and enabled API service from `admin > system > users > API` page.

I followed this [documentation](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/system/users/api/) and received access_token and it's visible in API > sessions tab.

Now I want to get list of products available via API but no method find in doc. Is any other API enable to get the products.

Please provide any reference docs.

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for OpenCart 3 then this may help:

[How to pull products json through API in Opencart?](https://webocreation.com/blog/pull-products-json-through-ap-opencart)

[View this youtube video](https://youtu.be/bc2govdEiuA) , it describes how to make custom OpenCart API and give details how to use it.

In Responding server, go to catalog/controller/api/ and create product.php and paste following lines of code:

```
<?php
class ControllerApiProduct extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->language('api/cart');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $json = array();
        $json['products'] = array();
        $filter_data = array();
        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
            } else {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
            }
            if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }
            if ((float) $result['special']) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $special = false;
            }
            if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                $tax = $this->currency->format((float) $result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $tax = false;
            }
            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $rating = (int) $result['rating'];
            } else {
                $rating = false;
            }
            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb' => $image,
                'name' => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price' => $price,
                'special' => $special,
                'tax' => $tax,
                'minimum' => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                'rating' => $result['rating'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
            );
        }
        $json['products'] = $data['products'];
        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
}
```

In your requesting server, create a file lets say apiproducts.php, and paste the following code and run it:

```
<?php
$url = "https://webocreation.com/nepalbuddha";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url . "/index.php?route=api%2Fproduct",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

You will get the response like below:

```
{
    "products": [{
        "product_id": "30",
        "thumb": "https:\/\/webocreation.com\/nepalbuddha\/image\/cache\/catalog\/demo\/canon_eos_5d_1-228x228.jpg",
        "name": "Canon EOS 5D",
        "description": "Canon's press material for the EOS 5D states that it 'defines (a) new D-SLR category', while we're n..",
        "price": "$122.00",
        "special": "$98.00",
        "tax": "$80.00",
        "minimum": "1",
        "rating": 0,
        "href": "https:\/\/webocreation.com\/nepalbuddha\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=30"
    }, {
        "product_id": "47",
        "thumb": "https:\/\/webocreation.com\/nepalbuddha\/image\/cache\/catalog\/demo\/hp_1-228x228.jpg",
        "name": "HP LP3065",
        "description": "Stop your co-workers in their tracks with the stunning new 30-inch diagonal HP LP3065 Flat Panel Mon..",
        "price": "$122.00",
        "special": false,
        "tax": "$100.00",
        "minimum": "1",
        "rating": 0,
        "href": "https:\/\/webocreation.com\/nepalbuddha\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=47"
    }]
}
```

You can check following Opencart API related posts:

https://webocreation.com/blog/pull-products-json-through-ap-opencart
https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-api-documentation-to-create-read-query-update-and-upsert
https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-api-documentation-developer

Comment: what if i want to get the category_id along with product / or list all product according to category id ??

Comment: In the above code find  $filter_data = array(); and replace it with  $filter_data =  array('filter_category_id' => CATEGORY_ID_YOU_WANT); with this you can filter products as per category id.

Answer (score 1):

Opencart **v.2.1.0.2**, **v.2.2.0.0** & **v.2.3.0.2**

In `/catalog/controller/api/`
- `cart.php`
- `coupon.php`
- `currency.php`
- `customer.php`
- `login.php`
- `order.php`
- `payment.php`
- `reward.php`
- `shipping.php`
- `voucher.php`

These are what you may use.
For all the other you will have to build it yourself.